# Keep element out of iron page

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I have an element inside iron pages formatted with styling to be located at a certain area. The problem is I want the element to only get stamped once or be kept out of the iron page but still be located where I want it. Is there a way for iron pages to ignore an element? so its not stamped multiple times per page?

Comment: please share code

Comment: Personally I don't really understand what you mean. Can you share some code snippets? And describe what's the problem now..